# What is this shounen manga about a female monster hunter?

Tags: buster-keel

There was a manga I read about 3 or 4 years ago and I'm having some trouble trying to find it again. It was a shounen manga, and the premise was that a girl was trying to either capture the most monsters, or become one of the best monster hunter in the world. She encounters someone on her travels who says that he's a monster trapped in human form, and he had bracelets and a neckband that enabled this. If I remember correctly, he was a sort of monkey-dragon hybrid, and that at the beginning he was able to morph one of his  arms into one much larger that was covered in scales and had claws at the ends.

The girl at the beginning was able to control his transformations, and the monsters characters goal was to regain his true form.

I can't remember much else besides that the boy had orange hair and was rude, that there was another character introduced that led to a dynamic similar to the main cast in Naruto, and that they had all three joined a monster hunting guild.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Was it [Bleach](http://myanimelist.net/manga/12/Bleach)? Its fine you read it about 3 to 4 years ago but was it made about 3 to 4 years ago?

Comment: I think it's Bleach too, but his two paragraphs sounds a bit different than Bleach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your description, I'm quite sure it is [**Buster Keel**](http://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=36335). Its serialization began in 2008 in Japan and completed with 12 volumes.

[image: Volume 1 Cover]

Here is the description from Baka-Updates:

> Keel, the hero of our story, is looking desperately for Siva the so called "best monster fighter" to retrieve something precious that he took away from him, on his search he joins a beginner monster fighter girl, along with her flying pig monster and goes for an adventure to find Siva who for some reason has been missing for two years.

The girl in the description, named [Lavie](http://busterkeel.wikia.com/wiki/Lavie_Heartful), is a monster hunter. She has a Devil Pig named Mippy as a monster partner, and she can enhance the power of the monster partner by playing her guitar. This works by having the monster partner wear a *contract ring*, which allows her *contract melody* to work.

During the fight with King Lizard in chapter 1, [Keel](http://busterkeel.wikia.com/wiki/Keel) wears a *contract ring* and tell Lavie to play her music. The result is that Keel's arm is restored to that of his original form (Dragon Ape).

[image: Keel with his arm restored]

It is shown in the same chapter that the collar on Keel's neck maintains him in human form and it was unsealed by Lavie's magic during the battle. Keel's goal is to find Siva (the person who defeated him and turn him into human form) and change back to his original form of Dragon Ape.

Comment: Oh that's it exactly! Thank you for the quick response!